# How can I vary my line thickness in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an example here

http://jsfiddle.net/8NzjH/

I'm trying to draw a thick middle line as follows:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
context.fillStyle = '#000000';

context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(50, 10);

context.save();
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.moveTo(10, 30);
context.lineTo(50, 30);
context.restore();

context.moveTo(10, 50);
context.lineTo(50, 50);

context.stroke();
```

What I do is save the context, change the line width, draw the line and then restore the context.  However the thicknesses of all lines are the same.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to start a new path with `beginPath()` for each line, set `lineWidth` and then `stroke()` the line for each.

Here is an adjustment (fiddle below):

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.strokeStyle = '#000000';

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(50, 10);
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();

//context.save(); no need to do this
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.moveTo(10, 30);
context.lineTo(50, 30);
context.stroke();

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 50);
context.lineTo(50, 50);
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();
```

If you don't use `beginPath()` you will just redraw all the lines over again which slows everything down over the course. If all lines where the same thickness you could have used a single `beginPath()` in the beginning.

You can also rearrange the code so that the lines with same thickness is grouped together under one path etc. For example:

```
context.beginPath(); //begin here
context.lineWidth = 2; //common width for the next two lines

context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(50, 10);

context.moveTo(10, 50);
context.lineTo(50, 50);

context.stroke(); //stroke here to draw them

context.beginPath(); //start new path for new thickness
context.lineWidth = 15;

context.moveTo(10, 30);
context.lineTo(50, 30);

context.stroke();
```

There is no need to `save()`/`restore()` context if you only adjusting a parameter or two as long as you keep track of them (as here we set `lineWidth` for each time. This is more efficient in this case).

Optionally just make a function like:

```
function drawLine(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, width, color) {

    if (typeof width === 'number') ctx.lineWidth = width;
    if (typeof color === 'string') ctx.strokeStyle = color;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Usage:

```
drawLine(context, 0, 0, 100, 100);  //width and color is optional
drawLine(context, 0, 0, 100, 100, 10);
drawLine(context, 0, 0, 100, 100, 10, '#f00');
```

Corrected fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/8NzjH/4/

Rearranged version:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/8NzjH/5/

Answer (score 0):

Does it works like expected?

http://jsfiddle.net/8NzjH/1/

```
context.lineWidth = 15;
context.stroke();
```

Comment: "I'm trying to draw a thick middle line as follows:"

Comment: Not quite I was hoping to get just the one in the middle to be thick.  I tried to update your code but now the first two are thick http://jsfiddle.net/8NzjH/3/